# Facebook user location using fb.api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

I want to allow my user's to login with facebook and while user do that i want to collect there information such as Name,Email,Location, Gender etc. There are two issues that i am facing

1. FB.api not always returns me user's location.
2. I am not able to get the user's birthday using user_birhtday. Code is given below.

   ```
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
       if (response.status === 'connected') {
           FB.api('/me?fields=age_range,name,location,email,gender', function(response) {
               //Get the user's Information
           });
       } else {
           FB.login(function(response) {
               if (response.authResponse) {
                   FB.api('/me?fields=age_range,name,location,email,gender', function(response) {
                       //Get the user's Information

                   });
               } else {
                   // User is not logged in
               }
           }, {
               scope : 'email'});
       }
   }, true);
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a very clear list of permissions that you have to ask to query various parts of user data. Refer to the permissions section on [user](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) page (scroll to the end of page) and add them into your scope parameter.

For birthday and location you have to make the following change:

```
-- scope : 'email' 
++ scope : ['email','user_birthday','user_location']
```

and add the

> birthday

field to your fields list.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I am getting undefined for value for birthday field.

Comment: it means, some of the users don't have birthday field or just don't want to share it with others ... or , do you mean you always getting undefined?

Comment: I am always getting undefined. How do you get the value? Using response.birthday ryt?

Comment: Can check if your access_token having user_birthday permissions on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/